# Convert existing index to unique (mongodb) using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have an existing index on a field using Morhia.

```
@Indexed
public String field;
```

now I want to convert that to a unique index.

```
@Indexed(unique = true)
public String field;
```

On application start, I call db.ensureIndexes() - however the uniqueness of the index is not reflected in mongo.

Why is this failing? Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: And the initial index has been created by Morphia and is still being created if you drop it? If no index is created any more, check that the ``ensureIndexes()`` is called on the correct package. I've once refactored my package structure but not at the ``ensureIndexes()`` call and couldn't figure out why the hell my indexes were no longer being created ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of an index in MongoDB can't be modified after creation; thus you cannot directly convert a non-unique index into a unique index.  You will have to drop the index manually before it can be recreated as a unique index.  You can do this directly with the mongo shell: see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-DroppingIndexes.